# Shared Library Dependency Removal in Websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have an application which contain portlets in which one project is common to all the projects. In the common project I have some shared lib and I have configured in websphere the same.

New Requirement is that I have to remove the shared library dependency and have to include all those libraries within the project itself. But when i do that I am getting ClassCastException which is correct because the common project is running in diff JVM and all other projects in diff one.

I have tried "install optional packages" approach but in vain.

Is there any way to resolve the issue.? Any Idea would be great to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

If your common project is mixed with shared classes, non-shared classes and resources, break out your common classes into a separate project with a separate `jar`. Then include that `jar` as a library in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web project containing your portlets. Some example structures are [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Java-WAR-files.html).

If you have multiple web projects and they are all within the same `ear`, you can also place your shared `jar` in the `ear` file. If you go for this solution, the `jar` will need to be added to the classpath for any module within the `ear` that needs access to it. You need to update the `MANIFEST.MF` file under the `META-INF` directory for the module which needs to access the jar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Common project is also a Web Project.

Comment: Ok, but what do you have in the shared library? Is that only classes from the common project or does it contain everything from the common project?

Comment: Only Classes compiled in jar and some portlet customized jars.

Comment: Not knowing the entire structure of your solution. If you have classes shared between multiple applications there are a couple of ways you can go. One is to break out your classes that are shared into a separate project. Then you add those classes in a jar that you include in all those web projects that need them.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I will consider your option.